# How to manipulate FileList type=file and sending via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need some help for my problem. I want to delete some files from a FileList and then send them via Ajax with new FormData. For this I only want to work with Javascript.

After the files have been selected by users, they are evaluated by the content_evaluate () function and the files to be sent are assigned to a new array transfer_files[]. These files are added to a new formdata and then sent.
However, all files from the origin input are sent even if only the modified array is given to the new formdata. e.g. **3 of 5 files have to be sent.**

```
<form id="formular" onsubmit="send_data();" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table id="dyninfo" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="upload_filename_id" name="upload_filename" type="file" 
        onchange="content_evaluate();" size="60" multiple>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" id="upload" style="width:120px">Upload</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Script:

```
 var transfer_files = [];
 function send_data()
 {
 var formData = new FormData();
 for (var i = 0; i < transfer_files.length; i++) 
 {
    var file = transfer_files[i];
    formData.set(transfer_files, file, file.name);
 }
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', 'upload.html', true);
 xhr.send(formData);

 return false;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You were looping through a 0 length array ( transfer_files )

## What you should have done instead:

Use the input file object to retrieve the inputted files, then you can loop through it

```
var inputFile = document.querySelector('#upload_filename_id'),
transfer_files = inputFile.files;

 function send_data()
 {
     var i, file, formData = new FormData();

     for ( i = 0; i < transfer_files.length; i++ ) 
     {
        file = transfer_files[ i ];

        formData.set( inputFile.name, file, file.name  );
     }

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('POST', 'upload.html', true);
     xhr.send(formData);

     return false;
 };
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :-). transfer_files contains the selected files and has length not '0'. this line transfer_files = inputFile.files; the array is overwritten again with the files from the input field. I want to transfer only the selected files. this means for example, 2 of 5 files have to be sent.

Comment: Alright, but if you want to select the files to send, that can't be done automatically, you'll have to retrieve the file index in the code and send it.

Comment: I found the problem. That was due to the "onsubmit". If the Ajax functionality is to be used for the upload, it must not run on onsubmit, as onsubmit transfers all files from the type field. In this case you just need to call the upload function in Javascript via onclick and only the selected files will be transferred